# webpack dist on php server has error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

I use webpack to build and generate a list of files, it works correctly when you just double click the index.html and open in browse. However, after I change the filename extension from .html to .php, and put the dist folder in server, it stop working and give me errors. The errors are:

```
common.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My index.php are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I feel like there is something wrong when send back the main.js and common.js to client side, because in both files it has **style type="text/css"** in main.js and common.js, which is not show in original dist files.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What did DevTools point to when you clicked the stack trace?

Comment: it points to the first line, since the js file start with < style type="text/css"> , which cause the error

Comment: Please show your webpack config; that's very odd.